# Are word timestamps always immediately consecutive and always start from 0?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

In google cloud speech to text, I'm getting the timestamps of the words as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-time-offsets#speech_transcribe_async_word_time_offsets_gcs-php) using PHP.

Two issues:
The first word always starts at 0s, even if the audio file doesn't have any sound until after.

Each word timestamp is immediately followed by another, even when the speaker pauses between words.

Is it possible to get a more precise word timestamp with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/basics#time-offsets), it seems there isn’t an option to modify any parameter in order to get a more precise word timestamp.

However, you can [report this issue](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=187181&template=1161156) by providing all the information requested within the form.

Comment: I imagine their timestamps will improve over the coming months/ years. I decided to use a different STT service as timestamps were an important feature.